# Deploying C# Application

Tags: c#

I ve written an application and compiled this into a shared folder that users should be referencing.

I want to create an installer application which calls a seperate '.exe' and also checks that the user has read / write access to the shared fodler.

I ve been trying to do this using the File->New->Setup Project

I cannot see an option for writing code to call the seperate '.exe' and also do some cheks.

Any ideas please??

Comment: What is the separate executable and why do you need to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform custom steps as part of your deployment/installation you can create a "custom action".

I have used this approach myself in the past and have found it very useful.  (It might now be superseded by a newer approach, but I'm not aware of one).

This [article gives a great tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CustomInstallMG11102005235312PM/CustomInstallMG.aspx) on custom actions in .NET.

Comment: If prerequisites are not met how do you stop the install using a custom action??

Comment: Also can you build a setup projet which does nothing apart from run the custom action???

Comment: You may want to look at Commit and Rollback Custom actions.  The Commit custom action checks for pre-requisites and if not found, can throw an exception to cause the installation to Rollback.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371369(VS.85).aspx

Comment: If you want an installer with nothing but a custom action, you might be better off just creating a standard exe project and performing install steps there.  As long as you provide a simple uninstall option you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), it is far much easier to set-up and has many features, including a compiled scripting language if you need to do some checkings at the installation and/or de-installation.

There is also a GUI provided as [3rd party software](http://www.istool.org/).

Also, you don't need to install anything else when you install a package made by Inno Setup, it creates independent .exe installers (unlike .msi files).

Comment: Cant use third party software- Sorry

Comment: It's a free installer builder, are you sure it's not allowed in the case of your application?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [creating a custom installer action](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx) in your setup project which allows you to run arbitrary code during different stages of the deployment.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the custom actions. It will allow you to execute arbitrary .Net code during installation.